# Decrypting a message without the Private Key

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, cryptography

I am given 5 different encryption modulus, N, each ranging from 78 to 88 numbers long. Then for the encryption exponent, each has the same which is 5. Then I am given 5 different encrypted messages, E, which also ranges from 76 to 88 numbers long. I am trying to decrypt the message without having to discover the private key.

One way is to use the Chinese Remainder Theorem where we follow the procedure as follwos: $x=E_i mod R_i$ for $i=1,2,3,4,5.$ So for $x$, I took all the combination for i and tried to decrypt it by taking the 5-th root of the solution I get for all the $x's$. However, this is not really working for me as for every solution I get for x, it is not possible to take the 5-th root without having decimal fraction. I am taking the 5-th root because my encryption exponent is 5.

Anyone who is familier with the procedure I am taking about, could you tell me what I am doing wrong and possibly help me through this? Thanks in advance. The method I am using is known as the common encryption exponent.

Comment: Because we encrypt the message using the encryption exponent, which is 5 in our case, we have to take the 5-th root since we are decrypting the message without the private key.

Comment: @Amzoti the key point is that he has 5 different ciphertexts for the *same* exponent and the *same* plaintext.

Comment: @hherkljkljkljklj You should take all the 5 equations into account and apply the CRT (once). Taking only two won't work.

Comment: Using the CRT. We can decrypt by x = Ei mod Ni where Ei is your encrypted message and Ri is your encryption modulus.

Comment: @ftfish I tried every possibility there is. I tried x=E1 mod N1, x=E1 mod N2, .... x=E5 mod R5. I went all the way across trying to see where I could get a perfect 5 root for any of my solutions x. But none are giving me the perfect 5-th root.

Comment: Then I cannot help more without seeing the numbers. Note that those moduli must be coprime for normal CRT. This can be generalized though.